# StreamWriter does not create a file, working on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

I have a problem with my code,

Xamarin does not inform with any errors and warnings but the file is still not created.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            int counter = 1;
            double init;
            double finish = 5.6;
            double step = 0.2;

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("file.dat"))

        for (init = 1.0; init <= finish; init = init + step)
        {
            if (init / 2 < 1.5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("init = " + init + "\t counter = " + counter + "\n");
                file.Write("init = " + init + "\t counter = " + counter + "\n");
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed Expression at " + init + " in " + counter + " turn!\n");
                file.Write("init = " + init + "\t counter = " + counter + "\n");
                counter = counter + 1;

            }
        }


    }
}
```

I'd like to write in a file same lines that are written to a console, but the file does not exist. I've checked the other posts and tried suggested variations of solutions yet the file is still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "test.dat" file will be written to the `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release` directory since you are not specifying any path for the file.

Example Output:

```
.
├── Program.cs
├── Properties
│   └── AssemblyInfo.cs
├── TestFileOutput.csproj
├── TestFileOutput.csproj.user
├── bin
│   └── Debug
│       ├── TestFileOutput.exe
│       ├── TestFileOutput.exe.mdb
│       └── file.dat
```